# Next.js 13 with experimental appDir is not rendering <meta> or <title> tags in <head> section on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying out Next.js 13's new [experimental `appDir`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/app-directory-roadmap), and I've run into a bit of a snag.

This project is built on:

- Next.js 13
- React 18
- [MUI 5](https://mui.com) (styled components, which use `@mui/system @emotion/react @emotion/styled`)

To get MUI/Emotion to play nice with server-side rendering, there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2928#issuecomment-1368709980) to handle the SSR cache, which suggests that I have to turn the `layout.tsx` into a client-only component. This means things like `<head>` will only render server-side now.

To work around *that*, I've split the layout into a server component with client leaf.

But no matter what I do, when I deploy on Vercel, I can't get `<title>` or any `<meta>` tags to appear in the `<head>` in the server source.

Here's an extract of what I've done. (Note: needs `experimental: { appDir: true }` in `next.config.js`).

```
// app/head.tsx

export default function Head() {
  return (
    <>
      <title>My App</title>
    </>
  )
}
```

```
// app/layout.tsx

import { SSRThemeProvider } from "lib/SSR/theme";
import React from "react";
import theme from "styles/appTheme";

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <html lang="en" key="root">
        <head />
      </html>
      {/* ^ duplicate html/head outside of client-only provider */}
      <SSRThemeProvider theme={theme} key="theme-provider">
        <html lang="en" key="root">
          {/*
            <head /> will contain the components returned by the nearest parent
            head.tsx. Find out more at https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head
          */}
          <head />
          <body>{children}</body>
        </html>
      </SSRThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}
```

```
// app/home.tsx

import { HomePage } from "content/home";
import { getPlaceholderImages } from "lib/SSR/placeholderImages";

export default async function HybridHome() {
  const images = await getPlaceholderImages();
  //                      ^ server-side stuff with sharp
  return <HomePage placeholderImages={images} />;
}
```

```
"use client"; 
// ^ client only directive
// lib/SSR/theme.provider.tsx

import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { DefaultTheme, ThemeProviderProps } from "@mui/styles";
import React from "react";

export const SSRThemeProvider = <T = DefaultTheme,>(
  props: ThemeProviderProps<T>
): React.ReactElement<ThemeProviderProps<T>> => {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <ThemeProvider {...props} />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};
```

```
"use client";
// ^ client only here too
// content/home.tsx

import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
import RootStyleRegistry from "lib/SSR/emotion";
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export const HomePage = () => {

  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline key="css-baseline" />
      <RootStyleRegistry>
        <main>
          {/* Words go here /*}
        </main>
      </RootStyleRegistry>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: **Since NextJS 13 became a stable release, the head.js file has been replaced in favour of the metadata object and generateMetadata options.**

More info: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, turns out this is an actual bug in `useQueryParams` per https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44868.

I replaced it temporarily with a custom hook instead, and now all my tags show up, even when I use @MayankKumar's suggestion and use `<head />` directly without another component.

Here's my hook while that ticket remains open:

```
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import isEqual from "react-fast-compare";

interface UrlEvents {
  routeChanged?: ({
    pathname,
    location,
  }: {
    pathname: string | null;
    location: Location | null;
  }) => void;
}

export const useNavigation = ({ on }: { on?: UrlEvents }) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const [location, setLocation] = useState<Location>();

  const { routeChanged } = on || {};

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname && typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
        if (!isEqual(window.location, location)) {
          setLocation(window.location);
          routeChanged?.({
            pathname,
            location: window.location,
          });
        }
      });

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("popstate", () => {});
      };
    }
  }, [location, pathname, routeChanged]);

  return location;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `head.tsx` component should return a fragment, not `head`.

Try this

```
  return (
    <>
      <title>My App</title>
    </>
  )
}
```

Secondly, you don't need to import this component anywhere. It is automatically added to the head section of corresponding page and sub-pages.

Comment: Ah, I had done this and various iterations thereof (this was a copy/paste error), but turns out it's not this – it appears to be an actual bug in `useQueryParams`.